# return json value through fetch function

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I am trying to output the players name from a JSON array using fetch and just returning it where I call it at for, I can insert the return into html elements.

The console logs the results I want perfectly but the return, returns undefined in the element.

JSON api example:

```
{
    "PlayerID": 10000439,
    "Jersey": 8,
    "Position": "RF",
    "FirstName": "Nick",
    "LastName": "Castellanos"
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="scoreboard">
        <div class="home">TEAM1<span class="runs"></span>0</div>
        <div class="away">TEAM2<span class="runs"></span>0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="batting">
        Batting:
        <span id="batterPlayerName">
        Player Name
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="pitching">
        Pitching:
        <span id="pitcherPlayerName">
        Player Name
    </span>
    </div>
```

JS

```
function PlayerName(id) {
     var url = `https://apiurl/Player/${id}`;
     fetch(url)
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => {
         console.log(`${data.FirstName} ${data.LastName}`)
         return data.FirstName + ' ' + data.LastName;
     })
}



var curBatter = document.querySelector('#batterPlayerName');
var curPitcher = document.querySelector('#pitcherPlayerName');

curBatter.innerHTML = PlayerName('10000439');
curPitcher.innerHTML = PlayerName('10000526');
```

console: Nick Castellanos
PlayerName div: Batting: undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to set the value of PlayerName before the fetch has resolved.

If you return the promise from your PlayerName function then you are able to set the innerHtml once the promise is resolved.

```
function PlayerName(id) {
    var url = `https://apiurl/Player/${id}`;
    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(`${data.FirstName} ${data.LastName}`)
            return data.FirstName + ' ' + data.LastName;
        })
}

PlayerName('10000439').then(player => {
    var nameDiv = document.querySelector('#PlayerName')
    nameDiv.innerHTML = `Batting: ${player}`;
})
```

Alternatively you can wrap the entire function to execute asynchronously

```
async function PlayerName(id) {
    var url = `https://apiurl/Player/${id}`;
    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(`${data.FirstName} ${data.LastName}`)
            return data.FirstName + ' ' + data.LastName;
        })
}



var curBatter = document.querySelector('#batterPlayerName');
var curPitcher = document.querySelector('#pitcherPlayerName');


(async () => {
    curBatter.innerHTML = await PlayerName('10000439');
    curPitcher.innerHTML = await PlayerName('10000526');
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must declare the HTML selector to the belonging JSON

Comment: I do not understand

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).